# How to address instance of anonymous class from inner anonymous class?

Tags: java

I have a code that contains anonymous class in another anonymous class and I need to address instance of outer anonymous class from inner anonymous class. Here is the code:

```
editTemplateButton.setAction(new AbstractAction("Edit...", GUIUtils.EDIT_ELEMENT_ICON)
        {
            {
                setEnabled(false); // disabled at start
                templatesList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
                    {
                        setEnabled(!templatesList.isSelectionEmpty()); // depends on selection
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //todo
            }
        });
```

So, I call `setEnabled()` of implementation of `AbstractAction` inside implementation of `ListSelectionListener`. Now it's called ok. But I want to put implementation of `ListSelectionListener` to variable and use it twice for different actions. How can I call `setEnabled()` properly? Please don't forget that outer `JFrame` contains this code is also have `setEnabled()` method and I don't want to call it instead of right one.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

**UPDATE:** I can't use construction like `AbstractAction.this.setEnabled(!templatesList.isSelectionEmpty());` because compiler reports error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Your should call :</strike>

```
AbstractAction.this.setEnabled(!(this.isSelectionEmpty()));
```

**UPDATE**
OK, You can proceed like this:

```
   final AbstractAction[] action = new AbstractAction[1];
   editTemplateButton.setAction(action[0]=new AbstractAction("Edit...", GUIUtils.EDIT_ELEMENT_ICON)
        {
            {
                setEnabled(false); // disabled at start
                templatesList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
                    {
                        action[0].setEnabled(!templatesList.isSelectionEmpty()); // depends on selection
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //todo
            }
        });
```

Comment: It's compiler error because AbstractAction isn't an enclosing class.

Comment: Ok, thanks. it's the answer. But I'll think about overall architecture of this solution... )

Answer (score 2):

i read it wrong. You can turn `AbstractAction` to a private non-anonymous inner class (for example `MyAction`) and then call it like `MyAction.this`